# About Poincare inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Assume $\Omega\subset R^n $ is a nice domain in $R^n$. I know that we can have the following control in sobolev space:

$  \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq C \|\nabla u \|_{L^2(\Omega)}, \forall u \in H^1_0(\Omega) \text{ or } u \in H^1(\Omega) \bigcap \{u: \int_\Omega u dx = 0  \}  $

My question is if we can prove the following: for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $C > 0$ such that $ \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq \epsilon \|u\|_{L^2(\partial \Omega)} + C \|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}, \forall u \in H^1(\Omega)$

Comment: here is a related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3421287/if-int-u-du2-dx-int-partial-uu2-dx-infty-is-int-u-u2-dx/3421544#3421544

Answer (score 0):

This is not true: Assume that the claim holds for some $\epsilon$. Now set $u\equiv 1$. Then
$$
|\Omega|^{1/2} \le \epsilon |\partial \Omega|^{1/2},
$$
where $|\Omega|$ and $|\partial \Omega|$ are the $d$ and $d-1$ dimensional measures of these sets, respectively.

This gives a lower bound on $\epsilon$.